# Get an element from an array of objects with an id in mongodb using nodejs and mongoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've a many documents like this

```
user:62e13ae4f9a38f7610e70bd7,
_id :62e13ae4f9a38f7610e70bdb
transactions:{

 {
            "amount": 50,
            "category": "Bills",
            "type": "Expense",
            "date": "2022-01-20T00:00:00.000Z",
            "_id": "62e13ae4f9a38f7610e70be0"
        },
        {
            "amount": 100,
            "category": "Lottery",
            "type": "Income",
            "date": "2022-01-20T00:00:00.000Z",
            "_id": "62e13ae4f9a38f7610e70be1"
        },
        {
            "amount": 200,
            "category": "Salary",
            "type": "Income",
            "date": "2022-01-20T00:00:00.000Z",
            "_id": "62e13ae4f9a38f7610e70be2"
        }
}
```

And I want to retrieve an object from the **transactions** array with a particular id (I only want that object )

I tried some methods like

```
      const transactions = await Transactions.find({
        user: req.user._id,
        "transactions._id": {$eq: req.params._id },
      });
```

```
  const transactions = await Transactions.find({
        user: req.user._id,
        "transactions": { _id: req.params._id },
      });
```

```
            const transactions = await Transactions.find({
        user: req.user._id,
        "transactions": { $elemMatch:{_id: req.params._id }},
      });
```

but nothing seems to be working, can anyone help me to solve this And please mention the mistake I made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to match the `transactions._id` directly:

```
"transactions._id": req.params._id
```

### Example

```
const transactions = await Transactions.find({
  user: req.user._id,
  "transactions._id": req.params._id
});
```

### Update

From the comment, it's possible to use projection as the second parameter of `.find()` to return only the object it found in the `transactions`.

```
const transactions = await Transactions.find({
  user: req.user._id,
  "transactions._id": req.params._id
}, { "transactions.$": 1 });
```

[More information](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)

Comment: thanks BTW:)  after some modification I got the answer now 
const transactions = await Transactions.find({
        user: req.user._id,
        "transactions._id":req.params.id ,
      }, {
        "transactions.$":1
      });

Comment: Oh, I missed that part, the answer is updated with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want that matching element, you have to use aggreation.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $unwind: "$transactions"
},
{
  $match: {
    "transactions.id": "idGoesHere"
  }
}
])
```

As you commented in the other answer, you could use `positional` operator to project the matching elements as well.

Comment: can tell me what does the $unwind do here

Comment: Unwind is an aggregation operator which temporarily reshapes the doc. Means one array element will be one separate doc.

Comment: Thanks for the help,but actually i don't need the aggregation here .